# When printing to my network printer, why am I getting an additional sheet with the error: typecheck?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, printing, printer

Since updating Ubuntu, now running 22.04.2 LTS, my home network printer, HP LaserJet 4050TN, is printing an additional sheet with the following error:

```
ERROR:
typecheck
Offending command:
idiv
Stack:
50000
--nostringval--
-mark-
```

It's been a few months since the updated software. Network printing worked fine before.
Is there a known fix for this problem?
If this is a printer problem, I'll check HP's website.

Answer (score 2):

#### What is `ERROR: typecheck`?

> **PostScript error: typecheck**
>
> A PostScript error: `typecheck` is one of the most common PostScript
> errors. It signals that the RIP encounters an operand of a wrong type
> – i.e. an operator expected one type of data and got something else.
> Most common causes
>
> - Typecheck errors are usually caused by corrupted data.
> - This may indicate a problem with the printer driver. Try reinstalling it if the error occurs printing from various
>   applications. Check the network and/or server if the error persists.
> - Try copying and pasting your data to a new document.
> - Try opening and resaving all images and drawings.

Source: [PostScript error: typecheck](https://www.prepressure.com/postscript/troubleshooting/errors/typecheck)

Answer (score 2):

A new driver was needed to fix the problem. I installed a newer driver from HP.  The printer is working now, actually better than before.